# Delete profile in firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I need to delete the users profile from firebase, thing is I have 3 collections petfiles, petsdetails and users which need to be deleted. As in when a user signs up, they can create a pet and create records for their pet. But when having to delete the user, it should delete all the pets and records the pet has (it could be up to any amount)

I havent tried anything as I dont really know how to solve this but this is my code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:vet_bookr/oScreens/petFiles.dart';

import '../constant.dart';

class UserDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  UserDetails({Key? key, required this.details}) : super(key: key);

  Map<String, dynamic> details;

  @override
  State<UserDetails> createState() => _UserDetailsState();
}

class _UserDetailsState extends State<UserDetails> {
  List<String> labels = ["Email", "Phone Number"];
  bool editableText = false;

  String imageUrl = "";

  List<String> petIds = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    nameController.text = widget.details["name"];
    ageController.text = widget.details["age"];

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> uploadImages({required String path}) async {
    try {
      final imageRef = storageRef.child(
          "Users/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}/${widget.details["id"]}");
      await imageRef.putFile(File(path));
      imageUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
      setState(() {});
      //print(imageRef.getDownloadURL());
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print("Function does work");
      SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(e.message!));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }

  bool isLoading = false;

  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final ageController = TextEditingController();

  XFile? profilePic;
  ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

  TextEditingController controllerChanger(index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return nameController;
    }
    if (index == 1) {
      return ageController;
    }

    return TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.sp),
                child: PopupMenuButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.more_vert,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context) {
                    return [
                      PopupMenuItem<int>(
                        value: 0,
                        child: Text("Edit Profile"),
                      ),
                      PopupMenuItem<int>(
                        value: 1,
                        child: Text("Delete Profile"),
                      ),
                    ];
                  },
                  onSelected: (value) async {
                    if (value == 0) {
                      setState(() {
                        editableText = true;
                      });
                      print(editableText);
                    } else if (value == 1) {
                      setState(() {
                        isLoading = true;
                      });

                      final ref = storageRef.child(
                          "Users/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}/${widget.details["id"]}");
                      await ref.delete();
                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("users")
                          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
                          .delete();

                      DocumentSnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> snap =
                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection("users")
                              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
                              .get();

                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("petDetails")
                          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
                          .update({
                        'pets': FieldValue.arrayRemove(snap.data()!["pets"]!),
                      });
                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("users")
                          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
                          .update({
                        'pets': FieldValue.arrayUnion(snap.data()!["pets"]!),
                      });
                      setState(() {
                        isLoading = false;
                      });
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  },
                ))
          ],
        ),
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
        body: isLoading
            ? Container(
                width: 1.sw,
                height: 0.4.sh,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 15.sp,
                      width: 15.sp,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        color: Color(0xffFF8B6A),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : SafeArea(
                child: Container(
                  //alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.sp),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          // sBox(h: 10),
                          Text(
                            'Pet Information',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xffF08519), fontSize: 0.05.sw),
                          ),
                          //      myPetTile()
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 0.05.sh,
                          ),
                          Stack(
                            children: [
                              CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 0.095.sh,
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xffFF8B6A),
                                backgroundImage: profilePic == null
                                    ? NetworkImage(
                                        widget.details["profilePicture"],
                                      )
                                    : null,
                                child: profilePic == null
                                    ? Container(
                                        width: 0,
                                        height: 0,
                                      )
                                    : ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                        child: Image.file(
                                          File(
                                            "${profilePic?.path}",
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                              ),
                              editableText
                                  ? Positioned(
                                      right: 0.025.sw,
                                      bottom: 0.005.sh,
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () async {
                                          profilePic = await ImagePicker()
                                              .pickImage(
                                                  source: ImageSource.gallery);
                                          setState(() {});
                                        },
                                        child: CircleAvatar(
                                          backgroundColor: Color(0xffFF8B6A),
                                          radius: 0.02.sh,
                                          child: Icon(
                                            Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                                            size: 0.05.sw,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Container(
                                      width: 0,
                                      height: 0,
                                    )
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 0.02.sh,
                          ),
                          ...List.generate(
                            2,
                            (index) => Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 0.02.sh, left: 0.05.sw, right: 0.05.sw),
                              child: TextField(
                                enabled: editableText,
                                controller: controllerChanger(index),
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 0.017.sh),
                                cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  label: Text(labels[index],
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 0.02.sh)),
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10.sp),
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Color(0xffFF8B6A))),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.sp),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10.sp),
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Color(0xffFF8B6A))),
                                  contentPadding:
                                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.sp),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          buttonWidget()
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool isLoadingEdit = false;

  Widget buttonWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 0.4.sw,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xffFF8B6A),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.sp),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (editableText) {
                    setState(() {
                      isLoadingEdit = true;
                    });
                    if (profilePic != null) {
                      final ref = storageRef.child(
                          "Users/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}/${widget.details["id"]}");
                      await ref.delete();
                      await uploadImages(path: profilePic!.path);
                    }
                    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("petsDetails")
                        .doc(widget.details["id"])
                        .update({
                      'name': nameController.text,
                      'age': ageController.text,
                      'breed': breedController.text,
                      'weight': weightController.text,
                      'profilePicture': profilePic != null
                          ? imageUrl
                          : widget.details["profilePicture"],
                      'lastVaccinationDate':
                          widget.details["lastVaccinationDate"]
                    });
                    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snap =
                        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection("users")
                            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
                            .get();

                    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("users")
                        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
                        .update({
                      'pets': FieldValue.arrayRemove(snap.data()!["pets"]!)
                    });

                    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("users")
                        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
                        .update({
                      'pets': FieldValue.arrayRemove(snap.data()!["pets"]!),
                    });
                    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("users")
                        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
                        .update({
                      'pets': FieldValue.arrayUnion(snap.data()!["pets"]!),
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    setState(() {
                      isLoadingEdit = false;
                      editableText = false;
                    });
                    const snackBar = SnackBar(
                      content: Text("Your pet's details have been changed"),
                    );
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                  } else {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PetFiles(
                          petId: widget.details["id"],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: isLoadingEdit
                    ? Container(
                        height: 15.sp,
                        width: 15.sp,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          strokeWidth: 2.sp,
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(
                        editableText ? "Save Changes" : "Pet Health Records",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 0.03.sw),
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 0.01.sh,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out their official docs for deleting collections [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections).

Or you can upgrade your project to blaze plan and use [this](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/delete-user-data) extension which takes care of it for you.

Alternatively you can use NodeJS and FirebaseFunctions to do this task for you. Use this code snippet

```dart
async function deleteCollection(db, collectionPath, batchSize) {
  const collectionRef = db.collection(collectionPath);
  const query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve).catch(reject);
  });
}

async function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve) {
  const snapshot = await query.get();

  const batchSize = snapshot.size;
  if (batchSize === 0) {
    // When there are no documents left, we are done
    resolve();
    return;
  }

  // Delete documents in a batch
  const batch = db.batch();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    batch.delete(doc.ref);
  });
  await batch.commit();

  // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
  // exploding the stack.
  process.nextTick(() => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve);
  });
}
index.js
```